# Looking for an incremental upload solution (changes only) on iOS

Tags: ios, google-drive-api, realm, dropbox, data-persistence

Is there a high-level platform solution for iOS for providing 'changes only' upload to a file. I am currently building app that is using a realm database and this realm file is written to all the time throughout the app's life-cycle. I don't want to upload a 3MB database every time there is a small change to database.

Is there a service that provides solution for my problem? I am not sure if Google Drive/Dropbox API provide a solution for this. Would love to get a lowdown on this from people who have faced this issue or used Google drive/Dropbox API.

Comment: The Dropbox API doesn't offer this, but we'll consider it a feature request.

Comment: Depending on the reason why you're wanting to upload a Realm file, you might consider trying out the Realm Mobile Platform. It synchronizes only the changes made between a local Realm and its equivalent on the server: https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-platform/ (Full disclosure: I work for Realm)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Spreadsheet API to make incremental changes/additions to a spreadsheet.